# IdentityServer4 setting Scope Secret

Tags: c#, identityserver4

What is the best method to set the Scope secret for an ApiResource? I have found plenty of references to IdentityServer3 in this regard but none of them carry over to the new release. A code example would be great. I'm pretty sure I'm just defining this wrong but can't for the life of me wrap my head around it. Here's my current code:

```
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeProgram.Configurations
{
    public class Scopes
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("MyAPI", "My API")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What do I add to this? What do I take away? I've read the docs through and through and can't find an instance specific to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in an overlooked portion of the docs here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/configuration/resources.html

Code in full appears as

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
{
    return new[]
    {
        // simple API with a single scope (in this case the scope name is the same as the api name)
        new ApiResource("api1", "Some API 1"),

        // expanded version if more control is needed
        new ApiResource
        {
            Name = "api2",

            // secret for using introspection endpoint
            ApiSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            // include the following using claims in access token (in addition to subject id)
            UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Name, JwtClaimTypes.Email }
            },

            // this API defines two scopes
            Scopes =
            {
                new Scope()
                {
                    Name = "api2.full_access",
                    DisplayName = "Full access to API 2",
                },
                new Scope
                {
                    Name = "api2.read_only",
                    DisplayName = "Read only access to API 2"
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```